# Console output (stdio) does not work on Windows cross-compiled with mingw32

Tags: c, windows, cross-compiling, mingw32, windows-console

I'm far from being a Windows programmer, not even a windows user, but now I should cross-compile an application to Windows using mingw32. My problem: console output does not work. It's a GUI application, compiled with `-mwindows`. I tried to use `AllocConsole()` which indeed produces a console window, but still no output from `printf()` and friends. I also tried to use `freopen()` on name `CONOUT$` also with/without using `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)`. These were mentioned by several resources that can help, but still no output at all in the console window. Now I feel lost as I can't imagine what I can do more, even MSDN pages seems to agree that I do the right thing (if I read them correctly ...), but still no output :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main ( void )
{
    FreeConsole(); // just to be sure we had no console before
    AllocConsole();
    // SetConsoleTitle("Test console");
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    sleep(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Simply compiled with (on Linux): `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o test.exe test.c -mwindows`

Please note, that the problem exists in a more complex software. In this example I may choose to use console application instead of GUI then, but what I have problem with, is an SDL2 application otherwise and can't be console application, just I need console too. The code above is only a test case. I also tried to comment call of `freopen()` and `setvbuf()` out, modify their order, etc, it didn't helped.

Comment: Right, that is the correct way to do this.  I suspect the program has the wrong entrypoint and starts executing at main().  The C runtime library must be initialized first, it must be mainCRTStartup when you use the Microsoft CRT.

Comment: I tried compiling your sample using i686-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC 4.6.3) on an Ubuntu box, and it builds fine and I can indeed execute it on a Win7 box and get the expected output. Try compiling with -Wall to see if there are any warnings.

Comment: @jpw It's 4.9.2 also with Ubuntu, btw. The only warning that I used sleep() without remembering to have prototype with the connect header included :) With wine, I get no console. Otherwise I have no windows at all, which makes testing hard ... But I asked a friend and he also told that no output on the console on a "real" Windows ... SDL2 otherwise is a fine stuff I have no problem without even testing on Windows :) Just this console issue is quite problematic now ...

Comment: Hans Passant: I see, though I don't know too much what it means, I tried to call `mainCRTStartup` now directly but it causes program hangs, not even console window shown. With mingw I can assign another main entry (I think) with `-Dmain=...` but it would be in conflict with my real software I have problem with, since SDL2 also uses another main entry point it seems. But with my simple test case I tried, and got unresolved symbol of `WinMain@16`. I start to feel that Windows is an overcomplicated stuff even for the most basic things, like having working stdio :) Ok, ok, my bad, I know ...

Comment: It is not enough just to allocate a console window, you also have to redirect stdin, stdout and stderr to that window.  This article from Windows Developer Journal (1997) describes how to do this...http://dslweb.nwnexus.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm

Comment: thurizas: thanks, though I haven't only tried to called `AllocConsole()` but I also used things article suggested by you mentioned as well, like the `CONOUT$` stuff with `freopen()` and switching I/O buffering off (I think that was it with that `setvbuf()` stuff ...). Ok, not the very same way, as I can see ... That is the problem that I haven't forgotten those, but still no luck. However thanks, I will analyze the examples there, maybe it can help to find something I haven't done correctly!

Comment: Hans Passant: Ok, I was lame to call `mainCRTStartup` since it calls `main()` resulting in an endless loop. Now I tried to protect myself with a flag variable to signal I've already done it, but still it does make any output, but at least it helped to avoid the infinite loop I've caused with my try :)

Comment: thurizas you should write an answer, to be able to accept that, since it seems it worked quite well, thanks :) Interestingly, I thought I did almost the same (just a more simple way) with using `freopen()` on `CONOUT$` etc, as some other resources suggested! However it seems not to be true, as it didn't worked, but the solution in the article you've mentioned worked well! Thanks again!

Comment: @LGBGáborLénárt,   to get the attention of another posted, their name must be prefixed with `@`, similar to the beginning of this comment,

Comment: @user3629249 surely, I did even before, just I forget sometimes :( It seems.

Comment: Note that in almost all cases, it would be much simpler to build the program as a console application.  That doesn't stop you from presenting a GUI, the Windows API works exactly the same either way.